# How display redirect variables?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have used redirect

```
return Redirect::to('/lk/payment_status')->with('message', 'Платеж успешно завершен’);
```

How display message variable `message` on `/lk/payment_status` page?

Comment: Please format your question, to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems you want to show some flash message after redirecting from page

```
if (Session::has('message')) {
    $value = Session::get('message');
}
```

now you can use `$value` and show it inside your page.

you can use this to get `session flash message` or even you can use `Flash` api

```
Flash::sucess('some message');
// now do redirection
```

inside your page you can use `flash` tag

```
{% flash %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ type }}">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endflash %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the payment_status page is a blade template (payment_status.blade.php) then you can easily output it using the {{ }} marking, like this -

```
{{ message }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
@if(session('message'))
    {{session('message')}} 
@endif
```

Comment: hi @priya he is using `October CMS` and engine is `twig` so `blade` will not work here